# How to make the viewpager below the tab in TabCarouselLibDemo?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

The TabCarouselLibDemo source is [here](https://bitbucket.org/adneal/tabcarousellib/wiki/Home). Thanks for the author's work.

The demo shows the `ViewPager` is below the tab, but in the xml, the `ViewPager` seems that it is at the top of the tab.

I think if you can see the demo you will understand what I mean.

I have a question about how to make the `ViewPager` below the tab? I have seen nothing about it in the code.
It makes me feel uncertain.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with how `RelativeLayout` draws its children. If the `ViewGroup` was a `LinearLayout` and the orientation was set to "**vertical**", the carousel would be placed below the `ViewPager`, like you're thinking. But that's not how `RelativeLayout` works.

As far as the content in the `ViewPager` being below the carousel, you have to look at the custom `Adapter` used. There's a layout called "**faux_carousel**" that's used to create a layout with the same dimensions as the actual carousel, without showing the carousel itself. That layout is placed at position "0" in the `Adapter` so that all of the other content (that's in the `ViewPager`) will rest below the fake carousel and therefore the real one too.

Comment: I see .i was go out in afternoon.before i went out . I think it may be there is a view in the postion of the carousel.but i have not think it was added in the dapter's 0 postion . I konw it clearly now .thanks .